# Force the position of an element in a mysql query

Tags: mysql

How to force the position of an element in the result of a SELECT Mysql query?
For example I have an "elements" table with this data :

```
id| name
1 | element1
2 | element2
3 | element3
...
5 | element5
```

I want to manually place the element with id = 5 in 2nd position:

```
id| name
1 | element1
5 | element5
2 | element2
...
3 | element3
```

With the query below, I can place the element first, but not in second or third position :

```
SELECT id, IF(id = 5, 1, 0) AS position
```

FROM elements ORDER BY position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the other ids, i can think of two ways:

```
(select * from mytable where id <> 5 limit 1)
union all
select * from mytable where id = 5
union all
(select * from mytable where id <> 5 limit 10000000000000 offset 1)
```

And

```
select *
from mytable
order by id = (select min(id) from mytable where id <> 5) desc,
         id = 5 desc,
         id asc
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/VCVZ23881

Even more flexible - You can put it at any position:

```
select *
from mytable
order by id <> 5 and id < (select id from mytable where id <> 5 limit 1 offset X) desc,
         id = 5 desc,
         id asc;
```

With `X = position - 1`

So if you want to put your row at position `7` you need to replace `X` with `6`

Demo: http://rextester.com/DMIXA59318

Answer (score 0):

You could use order by field  for assign an order based  on the field value

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY FIELD(id,1,5,2,3);
```